# Powershell regex replace only first hit

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to use a regular expression to replace the first character after a single hit, while using PowerShell.

No matter how I try, I can't seem to make it work. Here's what I'm talking about:

**Code:**

```
$info = 'AB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---'

$regex = [REGEX]'/*'
$regex.Replace($info,"/C",1)

$regex
```

**Output:**

```
/CAB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---
```

I'm simply trying to replace the `/F` in the expression with `/C`, but it fails every time.

I'm using `/*` since I don't really know what character will I find after the first `/` but that's what I want to replace in the end of the day.

I pretty sure this will be pretty simple but, as you can see, I'm, just not familiar enough with regular expressions.

Comment: have you tried escaping `*` and use `/\*` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, rather than just a comment I guess I'll add an answer. You can use a negative lookbehind to make sure that there are no /'s before what you are matching, so it will only match the first one. Also, as Noah stated the <kbd>*</kbd> is not a wildcard, <kbd>.</kbd> is. This will match any / plus 1 character that does not have another / anywhere before it in the string:

```
"(?<!/.*)/."
```

So in context to your code, it would look like this:

```
$info = 'AB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---'
$regex = [REGEX]"(?<!/)/."
$regex.Replace($info,"/C",1)
```

Those lines will output:

```
AB/C/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---
```

**Edit:** RegEx broken down at RegEx101: http://regex101.com/r/tI7oN1/1

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Pretty obvious I have a lot of reading/experimenting to do with regular expressions... Thank you to everyone that pitched in, it is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding * in regex. It is not a wildcard character.

The star in regex means capture 0 or more of the preceding items in the expression.
Wildcard in regex is actually a period.

Comment: Nah Noah, don't do that, just use a negative lookbehind: `$string -replace "(?<!/.*)/.", "/C"`

Comment: I tried to think of some ways for a minute to do it in one expression and was drawing blanks. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = 'AB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---' 
$regex = [REGEX]'/.'
 $regex.Replace($info,"/C",1)
```

Or simply:

```
$info -replace '^(.*?)/.','$1/C'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = 'AB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---'
$regex = [REGEX]'^([^/]*)/[a-zA-Z]'
$regex.Replace($info,"$1/C",1)
$regex
```

`^([^/]*)`  - this looks for anything but slashes at the beginning, captured in a group

`/[a-zA-Z]` - then a slash followed by a letter

The replacement puts back whatever was matched by the first group, and adds `/C`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the regex, you can accomplish the same thing with -split and -join:

```
$info = 'AB/F/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---'
$info -split '/.',2 -join '/C'

AB/C/*ZXCVBN/MTF/ ---
```

The ,2 will stop the split after the first match (2 elements).  Then re-join the elements with  /C.